# System.out.print and UTF-8 crashes in terminal and not in IDE (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, console, system.out

I have a project where I must send strings via terminal but I've detected that strings like "ç" or "ñ" are not displaying in terminal, they are replaced by "?"

I´ve searched and tried this options and none of them resolves...

Terminal image:
[image: Terminal Image]

Eclipse out:
[image]

```
import java.io.*;


public class Main {
    public static String toutf8(String s, int c) {
        try{
            return  (c > 0) ? new String(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8") :new String(s.getBytes("UTF-8"),"ISO-8859-1") ;
        } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String co = "ç´+`qa-a.d,alnk123";
        String iso;
        try {
            iso = new String(co.getBytes(),"ISO-8859-1");
            String utf = new String(co.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
            pt("Cadena original: " + co);
            pt("UTF-8:" + toutf8(co,1));
            pt("Normal: " +toutf8(co,0));
            pt("--------------------------------------");
            pt("Intento contra getBytes:");
            pt("Cadena original: " + co);
            pt("UTF-8: " + utf);
            pt("ISO-8859-1: " + iso );
            pt("--------------------------------------");
            pt("Intento con getBytes #2");
            gb(co);
            pt("--------------------------------------");
            pt("Intento con PrintWriter");
            pw("Pw: " + utf);



        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
    static void pt(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    static void pw(String s){
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        out.print(s);
    }
    static void gb(String s) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        byte[] x = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
        pt(x.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: UTF8-chars works on my terminal without problems (Bash in KDE-Konsole & XTerm on Debian)

Comment: It doesn't seem that your program crashes, it only outputs question marks instead of some characters. It's probably just a matter of fonts used by your terminal or incorrect locale. What does the command `locale` print  when you run it in your terminal?

Comment: LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=

Comment: In the project properties, I´ve set UTF-8 to the project. I´m using Terminal and iTerm with encoding UTF-8. The font I use is Ubuntu mono, I dont know what would make this kind of errors...

Comment: Thanks a lot Michal!!!! I've modified my .bash_profile settings, and it just worked!!!